# Parsing Specflow Test Results

Tags: c#, parsing, specflow

New to C# and working on one project using specflow for automating a module and in the process I am hitting one corner case where for some reason First Scenario gets failed and because of this rest of the scenarios are skipped.

I am trying to get the skipped Test Scenario details but not able to get any...

Looking for some inputs like which interface I need to implement and how can I associate the implemented interface in the project.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: In my first scenario I have one functions which checks whether the details are in DB or not ... if it fails to get any details , I am getting exception and the test case gets failed & because of this the remaining scenarios are skipped. Default specflow reports shows all the scenario details along with skipped scenarios... but the same I am not able to get them in my custom extent reports.